# Not getting Soap v2 response in xml

Tags: soap-api-v2

I am using Soap v2 api of magento 1.9.2. I am trying to get catalogCategoryTree response in xml but I am getting another format every time. I tried to add header below the starting line of php script, but after adding header I did not receive any response. Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Answer (score 1):

just check weather your code is properly written without error. below is my code and which is working fine

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://yourmagentohost.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('yourapiusername','yourapipassword');
$result = $client->catalogCategoryTree($session,5); // replace 5 with category id
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```